# PNGImage "Access violation" error at procedure end

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-7

I am using PNGImage library in my project, which entire GUI is made up of .png images, which i loaded to TImages at run-time. For some purposes i have to dynamically create plenty of components groups that are similar to each other. Every group consists of some TImages and have a button that lets user proceed to another page with more details about clicked item.

The code i am using:

```
procedure TMain_Frame.selection_click(Sender: TObject);
var id: string;
begin
  id := StringReplace(TLabel(sender).Name, 'label_item_select_', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  hide_created_components; // It does Free all components
  show_details(id);
end; // (1)
```

`Access violation` error occurs at `(1)`. The odd thing is that it happenes completly random: error may happen at the very first click or may not happen for 10 clicks. If no error occured, F8 leads me inside PNGImage library where some stuff is done. However when error occurs, F7/8 immediately throws it without doing what it has to. This problem happenes only when i go from dynamicaly created objects to static.

CPU window shows that error occured at this ASM code:

`movzx ecx, [edi]`

ecx value is 755A2E09, edi is 00000000

Is it correct to `.Free` all dynamically created components? Or should be `.Destroy` used instead? And why does PNGImage goes inside itself on procedure `end;`?

---

Demo:

```
unit Unit1;
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, pngimage, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure selection_click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure create_label;
var Button: TLabel;
begin
  Button := TLabel.Create(Form1);
  with Button do
  begin
    Name := 'dynamic_label_1';
    Parent := Form1;
    Autosize := false;
    Left := 100;
    Top := 100;
    Width := 150;
    Height := 20;
    Caption := 'Dynamic Label: Click Me';
    BringToFront;
    Cursor := crHandPoint;
  end;
  Button.OnClick := Form1.selection_click;
end;

procedure hide_dyn_label(L: TLabel; mode: boolean);
begin
  if mode then
  begin
    L.Free;
    Form1.Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(PAnsiChar('button_close.png'));
    Form1.Image1.Visible := true;
  end
  else
    create_label;
end;

procedure TForm1.selection_click(Sender: TObject);
var id: string;
begin
  id := StringReplace(TLabel(Sender).Name, 'dynamic_label_', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Form1.Button1.Visible := true;
  hide_dyn_label(Form1.FindComponent('dynamic_label_1') as TLabel, true);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  create_label;
  Form1.Image1.Visible := false;
  Form1.Button1.Visible := false;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Calling `Free` is fine. There's a defect in your code, but we cannot tell you what it is. Please make an MCVE.

Comment: Demo code (your MCVE) should be *here* in the question itself, not in some off-site location.

Comment: @moskito-x nope, i am using only 1 form in project

Comment: @lolbas : and `label_item_select_?` is still there after you clicked it ?

Comment: @moskito-x nope. It is one of dynamic components that gets Free after click

Comment: @lolbas : Have you set `label_item_select_?.parent := nil` before you free it ?

Comment: @moskito-x well, no, is it necessary? i added and tested this in demo, but still getting error

Comment: Are you perhaps using a timer to update contents of your components? If you are it is possible that in Timer event you are trying to update one of the components that no longer exists. Also when debugging OnTimer event would probably be fired right after you exit your selection click routine because the timeout interval has already passed during the time you were evaluating that method. And since Timer events and practically any other events are processed when your application is idle (no other methods are being executed) that would happen right after exiting your selection_click method.

Comment: @lolbas : you are aware of always free the same label `hide_dyn_label(Form1.FindComponent('dynamic_label_1')` ?

Comment: @SilverWarior no timers in my project..yet. components are created only upon calling `show_created_components` which is done in similar way the demo shows

Comment: @moskito-x yep. but it is recreated every time you click button1 :|

Comment: a dynamic label using a hardcoded free ?

Comment: @moskito-x not sure i get you right. Why "hardcoded"?

Comment: all dynamic labels using the same on click event ! but only label_1 is freed ?!

Comment: @moskito-x in Demo there is only one dynamic label which is getting freed. in my original project i free all of them

Comment: you have the right thing in your code, but you did'nt use it `id := StringReplace(...` ! . use `id` you have created !

Comment: In `selection_click` you have:

    `TLabel(Sender).Name`

But `selection_click` is attached to a button and so `Sender` is actually `TButton`. Why are you casting to `PAnsiChar`? Why on earth are you using `FindComponent`? Take a reference to the label that you create.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : `var Button: TLabel;`

Comment: @moskito-x Oh! What a mess.

Comment: You also should be using methods of the form rather than the global form variable.

Comment: @lolbas : try to avoid for properties of components to use, out of the class . Incorporate the methods in the class. So `procedure create_label;` should be `procedure Form1.create_label()` also for `procedure Form1.hide_dyn_label()` .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are freeing the `TLabel` while still in its `OnClick` event handler, `Selection_Click` which calls `hide_dyn_label()` which calls `L.Free`. You can't do that. Use some kind of delayed destruction, f.ex. with a boolean variable `FreeDynLabels` which you can check in `Application.OnIdle`. Or post a custom message to the form.

Comment: In my project, i was able to "fix" error by setting parent to nil when i need to hide elements, and Free them right before creating

Comment: @lolbas You do know that `TLabel` has a `Visible: boolean` property, don't you? But why free and recreate, why don't you just reuse the `TLabel`s if you keep them hanging around anyway?

Comment: yeaaa but the idea is to recreate it since in my case when user returns to list, some information might changed (on server side) so i have to recreate them to show changes